# pydantic basemodel breaks classmethod access to attributes

Tags: python, pydantic, class-method

I am trying to export some properties of a class in python. Introducing `pydantic` breaks the access to attributes in a classmethod.

Take this working example:

```
class Person:
    age: int = 25
    
    @classmethod
    def printAge(cls):
        print('The age is:', cls.age)
```

If I extend it towards `pydantic`, it somehow breaks

```
class Person(BaseModel):
    age: int = 25
    
    @classmethod
    def printAge(cls):
        print('The age is:', cls.age)
```

Raises the following error:

```
 type object 'Person' has no attribute 'age'
```

Anyone knows what is going on here ? And even more importantly, how to overcome the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BaseModel` class uses the `ModelMetaclass` metaclass to construct new model types. Part of this is transforming the class fields into `ModelField` instances. If you really need to introspect this data, you can use the `__fields__` attribute on the class to gain access to its configuration. In this case you can do:

```
class Person(BaseModel):
    age: int = 25

    @classmethod
    def printAge(cls):
        print('The age is:', cls.__fields__["age"].default)
```